# iPhone SDK Zoom/Resize Image with 2 fingers!! HELP

Tags: iphone, image, sdk, view, resize

Help, i need to make an app that has got some images and you need to resize them on the screen!! But how can i resize them with 2 finger dragging? 
Help me please! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding UIScrollView to your window as the first step. UIScrollView handles things like dragging and zooming in/out for you. All you have to do is put your Image inside that UIScrollView.

Comment: i dont need scroll view, because i dont need to zoom images, but scale them. and i have more that 30 images, and i drag them OUT of a scroll view, so i cant put scroll view in other scroll view.